# Laravel blade: how to select an item from an Eloquent collection by its key

Tags: php, laravel

In a PHP array you can do:

```php
$array = [
  1 => ['example', 'hello'],
  ... => [..., ...]
  114 => ['things', 'here'],
];
```

and then access one of these array items dynamically:

```php
$key = 114;
echo $array[$key];
```

My question is if you can do something similar in Blade with an Eloquent collection. What I would like to do is get the model by it's ID from a collection, something like:

```php
$collection = Product::all();
$model_key = 114;
echo $collection[$model_key];
```

Comment: Something like `echo $collection[114][0];` will return `things`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, just like the `find()` method on the query builder you can use it on a Collection like so:

```php
$collection = Product::all();
$model_key = 114;
dd($collection->find($model_key));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<select name="items">
   @foreach($array as $key=>$value)
     <option value={{$key}}>{{$value}}</option>
   @endforeach
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Eloquent query returns `Collection` instance.
If you will only need to find 1 record you can do:

```
return $collection->firstWhere('id', $id);
```

If you need to search multiple times then fastest solution will be:

```
$collection->keyBy('id');
return $collection[$id];
```

All collection methods: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/collections#available-methods

Answer (score 0):

You can map collection with key using `mapWithKeys()` and than you can use it with key as below:

```
$collection = Product::all();
$collection = $collection->mapWithKeys(function ($item) {
    return [$item['id'] => $item];
});
```

now you can use collection by key:

```
echo $collection[$model_key];
```

Answer (score 0):

From your example,

```
$collection = Product::all();
$model_key = 114;
echo $collection[$model_key];
```

The products are not stored using the `id` as the keys. Instead, the `id` of a product is a key in that particular product.
For example, `$collection` might contain

```
[
  ["id" => 12, "name"=> "Shirts"],
  ["id" => 13, "name"=> "Shorts"],
]
```

To find a product by `id`, you would need to use one of the available collection methods. I prefer the [firstWhere](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/collections#method-first-where) collection method.
And to use it, it would look like:

```
$collection = Product::all();
$model_key = 114;
$product = $collection->firstWhere('id', $model_key);
echo $product;
```